# SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder generates an invalid connection string

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, system.data.sqlite

I'm trying to build a valid connection string with the SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder (System.Data.SQLite v1.0.88.0) using either the datasource or the URI:

```vb
    Dim connectionBuilder = New SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
    connectionBuilder.DataSource = Path.Combine(datadir, "mydatabase.sqlite")
    connectionBuilder.Version = 3

    ' Open connection
    Dim connection As New SQLiteConnection(connectionBuilder.ConnectionString)
```

Or:

```
    Dim connectionBuilder = New SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder
    connectionBuilder.Uri = New Uri(Path.Combine(datadir, "mydatabase.sqlite")).AbsolutePath
    connectionBuilder.Version = 3

    ' Open connection
    Dim connection As New SQLiteConnection(connectionBuilder.ConnectionString)
```

Both generate the same connection string:

```
    uri=file:///C:/Users/myusername/Documents/Visual%20Studio%202010/Projects/myproject/myproject/bin/Debug/data/mydatabase.sqlite;version=3
```

The URI itself is valid, the connection string actually looks good, but when I try to open the connection, it generates a `NotSupportedException`due to the path format within SQLite:

```
       bei System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath)
       bei System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath)
       bei System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[]         pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
       bei System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String[] pathList, Boolean checkForDuplicates,         Boolean needFullPath)
       bei System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
       bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.ExpandFileName(String sourceFile, Boolean toFullPath) in c:\dev\sqlite\dotnet\System.Data.        SQLite\SQLiteConnection.cs:Zeile 2690.
       bei System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open() in c:\dev\sqlite\dotnet\System.Data.SQLite\SQLiteConnection.cs:Zeile 2009.
```

How can I prevent this short of building the connection string myself?

Comment: What does `datadir` return exactly?

Comment: @Chris: It's an absolute path to a directory as String. In my code, I've added File.Exists()-checks to make sure the SQLite-File is actually there. It is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to issues with UNC paths starting with two `\\`. Somehow, the `SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder` was escaping them incorrectly.

I've solved my issue by replacing the first `\\` with `\\\`:

```
connectionBuilder.DataSource = pathToFile.Replace("\\", "\\\")
```

Comment: Issue filed for System.Data.SQLite: http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview?name=01a6c83d51